# <logic:match> tag equivalent in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-1

hi i'm new to Struts2 migration so i need help in finding the equivalent tag for the following tag in Struts2 or what logic can i use to replace this tag because if i use `<logic:match>` tag it is giving a warning that unknown tag

```html
<logic:match property="mode" name="FRForm" value="copy" location="start">
    <tr>
        <td class="pageSubTitle">Copy Details</td>
    </tr>
</logic:match>
```

Comment: Use `<s:if>` tag and call some String method in it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply and can u just give me the example for the above senario because when i googeled the value for the property will be given directly and then they try to match with the substring in value attribute but here we matching with the variable value where its value i taken from form and compare with starting substring so please help in in putting this senario in codes..

Comment: can i use a condition like this <s:if test="%{#FRForm=='cop y'}">

Comment: Can you write the same condition in plain java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace FRForm with FRFORm.mode.the value that you  need to compare with "Copy"

Comment: thanks porkko i try with this and let you know how it works

Comment: @vijayashree: You shouldn't accept answer if you don't know if it is working or not.

Comment: @PorkkoM: Don't think this is the right answer. Can you show some code?